# What exactly happens during Forex transaction?

Tags: foreign-exchange, spreads, bid-ask

We are talking about Forex market.
I want to figure out what *exactly* happens when I process a transaction on this market.

Can you please correct me if I'm wrong:

Assume we are working on EURUSD pair with an EUR currency account.
At time t, there is a **Bid(t)** price and an **Ask(t)** price.

If I decide to open a **long position** with volume **v** at time **t** and to close it at time **t+n**.
My profits in EUR should be `((Bid(t+n) - Ask(t)) * v) / Ask(t+n) // converted back to EUR since I buy USD when I close the position`.

If I decide to open a **short position** with volume **v** at time **t** and to close it at time **t+n**.
My profits in EUR should be `(Bid(t) - Ask(t+n)) * v // no conversion since I buy EUR when I close the position`.